# How to update a org by another salesforce org?

Tags: api

I have 2 org org A and org B. Here I have to update the a different org B from org A. I am using streaming API to identify that the record is created, updated or deleted on org A. This much I have done. But I need to update B from A, how can it be possible can anyone here please help me out how can it be done.

Comment: Have you considered Salesforce to Salesforce? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce

Comment: Alex you should turn that comment into an answer, IMO.